# What's the VB code for auto-sorting a range of data based on a text value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic

I have a few columns, important among them being: **Tasks**, **Priority**, **Status**.

I want all rows of records where the **priority** says "**High**" to automatically update themselves and appear on the top of other records.

My knowledge of VB is limited to opening the VB editor. Please help.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to do. I have already set some conditional formatting to highlight all rows where **priority** shows as **high**. Now I need all those records (and the new records with "high" priority whenever added) to automatically appear on the top of other records.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Could you please share some sample data to test & Screen Shot of Expected output since Sorting rearranges Alphabetically so HIGH will be placed at H ,, is this you need?

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable table autofiltering.
2. Set conditional formatting for Status column, mark High values with some pleasant backcolor.
3. Insert the below code to the worksheet module. Edit column number, header cell address and backcolor value in the code as needed.

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 2 Then
       With AutoFilter.Sort
           .SortFields.Clear
           .SortFields.Add(Range("B1"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortTextAsNumbers).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
           .Header = xlYes
           .MatchCase = False
           .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
           .SortMethod = xlPinYin
           .Apply
       End With
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Now each change in column B will reorder your data table.

PS. The final rows order and the posession of changed row are unpredictable... You may refine the final order by setting more detailed sorting criteria.

PPS. Of course, you can do not use conditional formatting and sort by the value directly. So use this post as a sample, not a solution.

Comment: The colour operator for SortOnValue is not working for me. Is there a way to set a particular text –"high" in this case, instead of cell colour as sort value?

Comment: @PrasadShrivatsa Sorting by values as a text may posess "High" not as the most upper... for example, "Average" is less while sorting like text.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest set of VBA (Macro), will  help you to Sort Rows have has **High** in ascending order and after that fill with background color.*

**Before Sort:**

[image]

---

**After been Sorted:**

[image]

---

- Either press **Alt+F11** or **Right Click** the **Sheet Tab** to open VB editor.
- Copy & Paste these VBA code as Standard module.

  ```
   Sub SortDataWithoutHeader()

  Range("Test12A.xlsm!Newdata1").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   Call Highlight

   End Sub
  ```

---

```
    Sub Highlight()

     Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
     Dim MyRange As Range
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
      Set MyRange = Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
      For Each c In MyRange
      If c.Value = "High" Then

       c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
       Else

       c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
       End If

      Next

     End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- In this line, `Range("Test12A.xlsm!Newdata1")`, **Newdata1** is the **Named Range**, will avoid editing *Range to Sort* every time new row will be entered.
- `Interior.Color = vbGreen` , **vbGreen** is editable.

## Edited:

*This Code will Automatically Sort & organizing the Data set on every new entry and only highlight cells has text **High.***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
Range("C1").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

Call Highlight

Application.EnableEvents = False

 End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("C:C")

If cell.Value = "High" Then
cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbLightGreen
Else
cell.Interior.Color = xlNone

End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

*Adjust cell references in the VBA code as needed.*

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it's not quite working. All I am getting is entire rows highlighted in the green background where the priority in the target column is "high". The rows are not shifting to the top, nor is the code executing itself automatically. I might have made a mistake in copy-pasting it but could you just drop the colour part of the code and keep only the auto-updation of sorting?

Comment: @PrasadShrivatsa,,, I've used code to Highlight entire Row since the attached Screen Shot with the Question has entire Rows are highlighted. Now I'm updating my post & including Auto Sort Method also will only highlight cells in Green !!

Comment: When I said entire rows were getting highlighted, I meant the whole rows across all columns in the entire sheet. Anyway, thanks for the updated code. I will test and let you know here.

Comment: @PrasadShrivatsa,, yes I got the point so that I've suggested `Worksheet_Change event` along with `ONLY highlight text HIGH in green in Column particular`,, and *remember I test my solution properly before I post as Answer*,, and both are working !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Sortby() function. It worked so easily. The VBA code to someone like me (novice excel user) was very daunting.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you could add an example snippet of code for how the OP could use the function.